# UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES event not firing in custom plugin

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, events

I'm working on building out a custom plugin for Craft 3 to create a new element type called Events. Following the Craft docs for [creating edit pages](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/extend/cp-edit-pages.html), I hit the point where I'm trying to register my control panel routes via the `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` event. For some reason, however, the event listener in my plugin doesn't appear to be getting called for that event. Here's my main plugin class:

```php
<?php
namespace mynamespace\eventelement;

use Craft;
use craft\base\Plugin;
use craft\events\RegisterUrlRulesEvent;
use craft\web\Urlmanager;

use yii\base\Event;

class EventElementPlugin extends Plugin
{
    public static $plugin;

    public $schemaVersion = '1.0.0';
    public $hasCpSettings = false;
    public $hasCpSection = true;

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
        self::$plugin = $this;

        // Register the EventElement. This is firing.
        Event::on(
            Elements::class,
            Elements::EVENT_REGISTER_ELEMENT_TYPES,
            function (RegisterComponentTypesEvent $event) {
                $event->types[] = EventElement::class;
            }
        );

        // This is not firing.
        Event::on(
            UrlManager::class,
            UrlManager::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES,
            function (RegisterUrlRulesEvent $event) {

                Craft::info("Add my routes."); // <- This _doesn't_ appear in the logs

                $event->rules['event-element/events/new'] = 'event-element/events/edit';
                $event->rules['event-element/events/<eventId:\d+>'] = 'event-element/events/edit';
            }
        );


        Craft::info('Event Element plugin loaded'); // <- I see this in the logs.
    }


}
```

When loading the site, my logging message inside the event listener doesn't fire and those routes 404 since they don't get added. I know the plugin is being loaded though, since I'm seeing the 'Event Element plugin loaded' text in my logs. I'll add that the other event listeners I have in my `init()` method are firing as well; the `EVENT_REGISTER_ELEMENT_TYPES` is working to add my custom Event element type.

What's strange is that I'm using the [verbb/events](https://github.com/verbb/events) plugin as a reference guide for some of what I'm doing and they have a listener set up for the same `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` event that's working just fine ([GitHub source here](https://github.com/verbb/events/blob/df88bb70e462f21198ad50736a791cef9178d001/src/Events.php#L152)). I know this is running because I added a log to their event callback that I am seeing reflected in my logs.

Additionally, I tried adding a callback for the `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES` event for front-end routes, and that listener doesn't appear to be firing either.

Am I missing anything else I need to do to set up these event listeners?

Comment: Oh hey Nick! :D

Answer (score 1):

The `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` event only fires if you're loading a page in the Craft admin itself. If you're loading your site frontend it won't fire, you need to use `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES` instead.

You can see the logic around this [here](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/86dcff6444f0bda0ca56af2fd83d4e4cbcddeeb6/src/web/UrlManager.php#L311).

Comment: Yo Evan! Sorry if I wasn't clear - I am in the admin. I've got an index page in the CP to list all of my Event elements; when I reload this admin screen I'm seeing the logging message I've added to the `EVENT_REGISTER_CP_URL_RULES` in the verbb/events plugin, but not the logging message in my plugin for the same event callback.

Comment: Incidentally I also just tried adding a callback for the `EVENT_REGISTER_SITE_URL_RULES` event in my plugin, and that also doesn't seem to be firing when I load a page on the frontend.